# Featherlight YouTube video link - position play button over thumbnail doesn't link/open

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-element, featherlight.js

This is a great plugin, and works perfectly! However, I placed a play button over the thumbnail of my client's youtube video using the before pseudo-class. It displays, but there is no click event on the button.

How can I adjust it so that clicking on the play button will also open the video?

Working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bo4h7t6c/

```
<ul>
<li class='youtube'>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TZCh2px0dOs&#10;" data-featherlight="iframe" data-featherlight-iframe-width="640" 
data-featherlight-iframe-height="480" data-featherlight-iframe-frameborder="0" data-featherlight-iframe-allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"  
data-featherlight-iframe-allowfullscreen="true">
<div class="gc-li-display-container">
<img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/TZCh2px0dOs/default.jpg" class="youtub-image" alt="Play Video" width="95" height="71"></div>
            </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting main li before with z-index of 9, which is greater than inside items, so try using before psuedo class to inner div like this

```css
.inline { display: none }
.gc-li-display-container::before {
    content: '';
    background: url(//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0209/7620/files/youtube-play.png?3160547863319844836);
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    z-index: 9;
}
li{list-style:none outside none;position:relative;height:70px;width:100px;}
li a{position:relative;}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class='youtube'>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TZCh2px0dOs&#10;" data-featherlight="iframe" data-featherlight-iframe-width="640" data-featherlight-iframe-height="480" data-featherlight-iframe-frameborder="0" data-featherlight-iframe-allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" data-featherlight-iframe-allowfullscreen="true"><div class="gc-li-display-container"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/TZCh2px0dOs/default.jpg" class="youtub-image" alt="Play Video" width="95" height="71"></div>
            </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You added the button as `::before` of the `li` so it is on top of the other child - `a`. put the `::before` on the `a`, and it will work (and you need to re-position it - change the `top` and `left`).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/598918/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple hack,

You can add to the `:before` pseudo two css property which is `user-select: none;pointer-events: none;` this will make the button like if it does not exist, so when user click on it he will be actually clicking the video and it will play.
Therefore, you can place your button anywhere inside the video and it will still work.

Check the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bo4h7t6c/7/).

Comment: Thank you - the fiddle works perfectly. I would have marked it right if I could for more than one!

Comment: It's ok, glad to hear it helped :)